# Changing matrix to character variable in loop R

Tags: r, function, loops

A quick summary: I am trying to apply dim(x)<-NULL within a loop or function in R

I am using the package colordistance in R. The function I am trying to create a loop for works like this for individual cases:

```
image_folders <- dir(path='./photos/', full.names = T)
image_1 <- sapply(image_folders[1], colordistance::getImagePaths)
dim(image_1) <- NULL
```

Currently I have tried creating a function as so:

```
list_images <- function(folder,index){
  require(colordistance)
  sapply(folder[index],colordistance::getImagePaths)
}
```

And then called this in a loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(image_folders)){
  name <- paste("image", basename(image_folders[i]), sep="_" )
  assign(name, list_images(image_folders, i))
}
```

However, this results in a matrix for each image list. I need to include `dim(image_1)<-NULL` to get them into character variables for following analyses.

I have tried placing this within the function and in the loop but this either results in values all with NULL or doesnt seem to do anything.

My expected outcome is to have character in my global environment "values" section with the names of all images in each of the folders provided to the loop. I do not want these in the "data" section of my global env.

Am I over complicating this?
How can I achieve my goal? - thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, but, yes, since you are using `assign`, you are over-complicating this. In 8 years of programming with R, I've never needed to use `assign` (maybe with the exception of answering some obscure question on Stack Overflow, but these should have been avoided by proper software design).

Comment: Ah ok, I have a habit of over-complicating things. Ill have another look to see what I can use instead of assign() - Thank you!

Comment: Usually, you should just use a list ...